# How to delete a registry value in C#

Tags: c#, registry

I can get/set registry values using the Microsoft.Win32.Registry class. For example,

```
Microsoft.Win32.Registry.SetValue(
    @"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run",
    "MyApp", 
    Application.ExecutablePath);
```

But I can't delete any value. How do I delete a registry value?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

To delete the value set in your question:

```
string keyName = @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run";
using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(keyName, true))
{
    if (key == null)
    {
        // Key doesn't exist. Do whatever you want to handle
        // this case
    }
    else
    {
        key.DeleteValue("MyApp");
    }
}
```

Look at the docs for [`Registry.CurrentUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.currentuser.aspx), [`RegistryKey.OpenSubKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xthy8s8d.aspx) and [`RegistryKey.DeleteValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk8b3th2.aspx) for more info.

Comment: How can i delete whole folder? suppose i want to delete `@"Software\TeamViewer";`

Comment: Use Registry.CurrentUser.DeleteSubKeyTree(rootKey)

Comment: Thanks! I was missing the "true" value indicating I needed to write access to the key to delete it.

Comment: Note: Use ```key.DeleteValue("MyApp", false)``` if you don't want it to throw an error if the value doesn't exist.

Comment: If you have a key but still getting a null key, see this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13729137/2286867

Answer (score 18):

To delete all subkeys/values in the tree (~recursively), here's an extension method that I use:

```
public static void DeleteSubKeyTree(this RegistryKey key, string subkey, 
    bool throwOnMissingSubKey)
{
    if (!throwOnMissingSubKey && key.OpenSubKey(subkey) == null) { return; }
    key.DeleteSubKeyTree(subkey);
}
```

Usage:

```
string keyName = @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run";
using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(keyName, true))
{
   key.DeleteSubKeyTree("MyApp",false);   
}
```

Comment: Looks a like some one working on .NET thought this was a good idea too :) Was added for .NET 4.0 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd411622.aspx

Comment: Just a point to note, if the second argument in `DeleteSubKeyTree()` is not specified it will assume it true and will throw exception unless the key is closed after `OpenSubKey()` is called.

Answer (score 15):

```
RegistryKey registrykeyHKLM = Registry.LocalMachine;
string keyPath = @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\MyApp";

registrykeyHKLM.DeleteValue(keyPath);
registrykeyHKLM.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

[`RegistryKey.DeleteValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.deletevalue.aspx)

Comment: how to get RegistryKey object

Comment: DeleteValue is not static method

Answer (score 0):

```
 string explorerKeyPath = @"Software\TestKey";
 using (RegistryKey explorerKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(explorerKeyPath, writable: true))
 {
     if (explorerKey != null)
     {
         explorerKey.DeleteSubKeyTree("TestSubKey");
     }
 }
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

I Needed something a little different, I just needed to delete everything a key contained. Therefore the below

```
Registry.LocalMachine.DeleteSubKeyTree(@"SOFTWARE\YourNeededKeyThatHasMany\");
```

Note that here its using LocalMachine so it's looking in "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" for the Key to delete its SubTreeKeys. Was simpler for me to do this and would've liked to see this simple answer here.

Comment: you should make a different question entry, even if your question is a bit different