# How to delete from the registry using C#

Tags: c#

I have this code that put an empty string in Autorun. I need to delete this Autorun.

How can I do it?

```
Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows CE Services\AutoStartOnDisconnect", "AutoRun", "");
```

Comment: Although I have answered the question, this question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531151/how-to-delete-registry-value-in-c , which includes a more full answer than I have given here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want some more defensive coding in case the key/values don't exist (or the user doesn't have permissions to delete it), but the basics are:

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows CE Services\AutoStartOnDisconnect", true);
key.DeleteValue("AutoRun", true);
```