# OpenSubKey() returns null for a registry key that I can see in regedit.exe

Tags: c#, registry

I'm trying to get all the display names of the sub keys within this key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

With this code:

```cs
     RegistryKey newKey;
     string val;

     string KeyPath64Bit = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
     RegistryKey mainKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(KeyPath64Bit);

     string[] RegKeys64Bits = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(KeyPath64Bit).GetSubKeyNames();

     foreach (string s in RegKeys64Bits)
     {
        newKey = mainKey.OpenSubKey(s);
        val = newKey.GetValue("DisplayName", -1, RegistryValueOptions.None).ToString();
        if (val != "-1")
           file64.WriteLine(val);
     }
```

After running the code I can't find one of the keys I need:

```cs
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{DA5E371C-6333-3D8A-93A4-6FD5B20BCC6E}
```

And it should have the display name: Microsoft Visual C++ 2010  x64 Redistributable - 10.0.30319, but instead the `GetSubKeyNames()` method gives me the sub key : `{DA5E371C-6333-3D8A-93A4-6FD5B20BCC6E}.KB2151757` which doesn't have any display name.

Why can't I get the exact sub key I need (`{DA5E371C-6333-3D8A-93A4-6FD5B20BCC6E}`) and how can I get it?

Answer (score 218, accepted):

A 32-bit application on a 64-bit OS will be looking at the `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node` node by default. To read the 64-bit version of the key, you'll need to specify the `RegistryView`:

```
using (var hklm = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64))
using (var key = hklm.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"))
{
   // key now points to the 64-bit key
}
```

The API to do this was added in .NET 4.0; if you're still using 3.5, you'll need to use P/Invoke to access the 64-bit keys:
http://www.rhyous.com/2011/01/24/how-read-the-64-bit-registry-from-a-32-bit-application-or-vice-versa/

Comment: Thanks for this. Although I still don't understand why there are two registries.

Comment: @RobertNoack: I think it's mainly for COM, and to ensure that environment variables get expanded correctly in `REG_EXPAND_SZ` values. There's some information on MSDN - [Registry Redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: You saved my day. I was getting freaked out with the way registry key was behaving for me. +1.

Comment: I must have read a dozen explainers; this is the first to show the 

RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64))

step.  Thanks!!

Comment: I run with Debug\x64 dotnet 4.6.1, but problem still exists. I can read the same path in another C# project with the same code.

Answer (score 24):

In Visual Studio 2017 go to

```
Project > Properties > Build > Uncheck **Prefer 32-bit** and Platform target as **Any CPU**.
```

Comment: I had the same issue - I unchecked 32Bit and it worked fine.