# "DisplayName" subkey value showing up blank

Tags: c#, registry

I made a console application to retrieve the "`DisplayName`" values of all the registryKeys `(RegistryKey.GetValue("DisplayName")` of applications installed on my machine.

I took that method, which was successful, and have implemented it in a program using the Autodesk Revit API. The problem is, the specific application's `DisplayName` that I am looking for does not show up, or it is a blank string. This did not happen before in my simple console application. I need this because I need to be able to grab the installation path.

Does anyone have an answer as to why the same method does not display the "`DisplayName`" value consistently in both my console application and in `Autodesk Revit`? Many `DisplayName` values do show up, but some apparently do not.

Comment: Could it be a 64/32-bit issue? http://stackoverflow.com/q/13728491/124386

Comment: Oh, I think you are on to something. Revit is 64 bit and I am using Win32.

Comment: @RichardDeeming I am new to developing. Is there not a Microsoft.Win64 class library like there is a Win32? I am running Windows 7, which is 64 bit.

Comment: `Microsoft.Win32` is correct; you just need to look at both the 64-bit and 32-bit registry keys. From a 64-bit process, the 32-bit keys will be under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\`.