# Getting blank InstallDate for few installed softwares, even if date is there in registry

Tags: c#, windows-7, registry

I am using below code to get list of installed software, i am able to get installation date for around 90% software but for around 10% software, i am getting blank in installation date **(even though the installdate is present in their registry key)**

```
key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall");
    foreach (String keyName in key.GetSubKeyNames())
    {
       RegistryKey subkey = key.OpenSubKey(keyName);
       string appname = subkey.GetValue("DisplayName") as string;
       string Vendor_Publisher = Convert.ToString(subkey.GetValue("Publisher"));
       string Version = Convert.ToString(subkey.GetValue("DisplayVersion"));
       string InstallDate = Convert.ToString(subkey.GetValue("InstallDate"));
    }
```

The application is installed on windows 7 (32-bit)
[image: InstallDate]

Comment: Share `FormatDateTime()` code

Comment: @Arshad, i am getting value blank for installdate even before that method call...

Comment: are you able to see while debugging ? Share the screenshot

Comment: @arshyad: i have uploaded debug info

Comment: and did you check install date in registry for this app

Comment: Just a wild guess, did the application with missing `InstallDate` is installed on 64 bit machine? See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728491/opensubkey-returns-null-for-a-registry-key-that-i-can-see-in-regedit-exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i have found that... All keys may not be present for all entry in the registry. So my suggestion is to check whether that key is present or not :
You can registry entry with `subkey.GetValueNames():

```
string registry_key = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
using (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(registry_key))
{
    RegistryKey subkey = null;
    try
    {
        foreach (string subkey_name in key.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            subkey = key.OpenSubKey(subkey_name);

        string[] columns = subkey.GetValueNames();
        string appname = subkey.GetValue("DisplayName") as string;
        string Vendor_Publisher = Convert.ToString(subkey.GetValue("Publisher"));
        string Version = Convert.ToString(subkey.GetValue("DisplayVersion"));
        if (columns.Contains("InstallDate"))
        {
            string InstallDate = Convert.ToString(subkey.GetValue("InstallDate"));
        }

    }
 }
catch (Exception ex)
 {
    throw ex;
 }
}
```

You can put the check for all the entries you are reading.

Comment: I checked in registory and those software has the installdate present, but don't know why its returning blank installdate in my code for them..

Comment: @Dr.RajeshRolen, I am facing similar issue. Did you find any solution to this?