# Returning a registry value as a string

Tags: c#

I am trying to read another applications registry value but I am not having much success. I have searched a full page and a half of results on Google, but not found what I am looking for.

I am trying to read the following registry value:

```
\\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\AVG CloudCare\DisplayVersion
```

A typical value would be: '3.5.3'

I am using this code which I found online:

```
RegistryKey RegInfo = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\AVG CloudCare", false);

object CCVersionReg = RegInfo.GetValue("DisplayVersion", "0");

Console.WriteLine(CCVersionReg);
Console.ReadLine();
```

However I always get an error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.".

I tried to convert the object to a string like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(CCVersionReg.ToString);
```

This also doesn't work, with the error, "Cannot convert to 'method group' from 'bool'.

The reason I need this is to compare this version with the known latest version for an updater application, which I need to use string to compare the values.

Comment: Did you verify that the key is actually present on the machine you're running it on?

Comment: `RegInfo` is probably `null` as you forgot the `Wow6432Node` part in your subkey string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var key = @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\AVG CloudCare";
Console.WriteLine(Registry.GetValue(key, "DisplayVersion", "0")?.ToString());
```

When `ToString()` is invoked on a `null` object, it throws `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Comment: Many thanks this has done the job. Much simpler than what I had been trying!

Answer (score 2):

Your error

```
Console.WriteLine(CCVersionReg.ToString);
```

is throwing that error because CCVersion.ToString is a method group. You will need to invoke the method by doing this:

```
Console.WriteLine(CCVersionReg.ToString());
```

However, you will get a null reference exception(as you are seeing) if CCVersionReg is null. Check that it gets created properly

Answer (score 0):

Is your application 32-bit running on a 64-bit OS ?
If so, please see: [OpenSubKey() returns null for a registry key that I can see in regedit.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728491/opensubkey-returns-null-for-a-registry-key-that-i-can-see-in-regedit-exe)