# How to get Windows Version - as in "Windows 10, version 1607"?

Tags: c#, windows

It seems that the word "version" in reference to Windows is used for different things. For example, the Windows 10 "Anniversary Update" is labeled "Version 1607" by Microsoft ([here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3176938) for example). But if I try to get the "Version" (on a PC with the Anniversary Update installed) using the following code, nothing is returned that looks like "1607".

```
// Get Version details
Version ver = os.Version;
Console.WriteLine("Major version: " + ver.Major);
Console.WriteLine("Major Revision: " + ver.MajorRevision);
Console.WriteLine("Minor version: " + ver.Minor);
Console.WriteLine("Minor Revision: " + ver.MinorRevision);
Console.WriteLine("Build: " + ver.Build);
```

I get this:

```
Major version: 6
Major Revision: 0
Minor version: 2
Minor Revision: 0
Build: 9200
```

How do I get the Windows 10 "version" as in "Version 1607"?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want Environment.OSVersion to reflect the correct Windows Build version, see answer about creating an app manifest file here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40672109/get-current-version-os-in-windows-10-in-c-sharp  .   May be more useful than the year-and-month style version number in case the user is getting Insider Updates

Answer (score 42, accepted):

according to [MSDN official link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724832(v=vs.85).aspx) there's a specific version number for each windows version out there. in dot net this can be read using the Environment.OSVersion object.

```
Console.WriteLine("OSVersion: {0}", Environment.OSVersion);
//output: OSVersion: Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0
```

What you are looking for is called  ReleaseID not a version of windows.
this be can read from registry key:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ReleaseId

```
using Microsoft.Win32;

string releaseId = Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", "ReleaseId", "").ToString();
Console.WriteLine(releaseId);
```

Comment: Excellent! Verified to work on my PC with "Windows 10 version 1511" and another PC with "version 1607" -- which is what was expected.

Comment: @Stavm — great info. BTW, Microsoft **does** refer to the _ReleaseId_ (e.g., "1803") as a Version, see [Windows 10 release information](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows-10/release-information) for details.

Comment: In addition, the original (RTM) version of Windows 10 does **not** have this key (just like Windows 7 or other windows versions)

Comment: On Win7, string releaseId returns empty.

Comment: this no longer works. microsoft broke releaseid for 21h1. you'd have to use diplayversion instead for 21h1, which might also break in the future and wont work for older oses.

Answer (score 5):

```
string Version = (string)Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", "ProductName", null);
```

Gives a name like "Windows 10 Enterprise".

Comment: This was already posted as an answer a few months ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49835788/1364007).

Answer (score 3):

```
 private static ManagementObject GetMngObj(string className)
    {
        var wmi = new ManagementClass(className);

        foreach (var o in wmi.GetInstances())
        {
            var mo = (ManagementObject)o;
            if (mo != null) return mo;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static string GetOsVer()
    {
        try
        {
            ManagementObject mo = GetMngObj("Win32_OperatingSystem");

            if (null == mo)
                return string.Empty;

            return mo["Version"] as string;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

How to Use:

```
Console.WriteLine(GetOsVer());
```

Result: 10.0.0.1299

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Scott's answer, you can also get the product name (ex. Windows 10 Pro) with this (*I take no credit as Scott is the one who mentioned the registry path + I'm reusing his code below):

```
using Microsoft.Win32;

string ProductName = 
Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", "ProductName", "").ToString();
Console.WriteLine(ProductName);
```

Comment: Dealing with 32 / 64 bits; 32 bits application in 64bits OS can retrieve wrong values. Check this thread [stackLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728491/opensubkey-returns-null-for-a-registry-key-that-i-can-see-in-regedit-exe)