# Get current version OS in Windows 10 in C#

Tags: c#, operating-system, windows-10, version

I Use C#. I try to get the current version of the OS:

```
OperatingSystem os = Environment.OSVersion;
Version ver = os.Version;
```

I get on the ***Windows 10***:  **6.2**.

But **6.2** is *Windows 8* or *WindowsServer 2012* ([Detect Windows version in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819934/detect-windows-version-in-net))

I found the following solution ([How can I detect if my app is running on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31885302/how-can-i-detect-if-my-app-is-running-on-windows-10)).

```
static bool IsWindows10()
{
  var reg = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion");
  string productName = (string)reg.GetValue("ProductName");
  return productName.StartsWith("Windows 10");
}
```

This is the **best** way to get the current version in C#?

Comment: Maybe check at this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331826/get-os-version-friendly-name-in-c-sharp

Comment: @olga have you added the manifest + supportedOS guids?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add [application manifest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374191%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to your application and add the [supportedOS Id](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/dn481241(v=vs.85).aspx) of Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 to the manifest:

```
<compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1"> 
        <application> 
            <!-- Windows 10 --> 
            <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}"/>
            <!-- Windows 8.1 -->
            <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}"/>
        </application> 
    </compatibility>
```

Now `Environment.OSVersion` includes the correct data for Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 and not 6.2 to indicate you run Windows 8. This is a [change since Windows 8.1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms724451(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link from Microsoft offical, indicating [how to get the System Version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms724429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It actually is a call to the [Version API Helper Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/dn424972(v=vs.85).aspx)

So basically you must convert this code into C# because it's in C++, then keep only the Windows 10 part...

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <VersionHelpers.h>

int 
__cdecl
wmain(
    __in int argc, 
    __in_ecount(argc) PCWSTR argv[]
    )
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(argc);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(argv);
    if (IsWindows10OrGreater())
    {
        printf("Windows10OrGreater\n");
    }
}
```

And if you like trying to read code, you can check out [this one link](http://www.csharp411.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/OSInfo.cs). This DLL can be used to get information on the OS...

Answer (score 0):

I have created this simple method in C# and it has worked for me.

```
    public static string GetWindowsVersion()
    {
        string registryPath = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion";
        string build = null;
        int number = 0;

        try
        {
            build = Registry.GetValue(registryPath, "CurrentBuild", null).ToString();
        }
        catch { return null; }

        number = Int32.Parse(build);

        if (number == 7601)
            return "Windows 7";
        else if (number == 9200)
            return "Windows 8";
        else if (number == 9600)
            return "Windows 8.1";
        else if (number >= 10240 && number <= 19045)
            return "Windows 10";
        else if (number >= 22000)
            return "Windows 11";
        else
            return "Older version";

        /* Go here to find more build numbers and evaluate more conditions
         * 
         * https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_Windows_versions
         * 
         */ 
    }
```