# MSVC OSVersion returning incorrect version

Tags: c++, visual-studio, powershell, visual-c++, windows-10

Running Windows 10 on my development machine. Trying to get the OS version to return a major version of 10. [Tried this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724834(v=vs.85).aspx) and also tried environment variables via `System::Environment::OSVersion->VersionString`. Both are returning `Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200`. Tested executable on a Windows 7 machine and I get `6.1.*` (correct).

Running this in Powershell I get the correct result:

```
PS Z:\> [System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
10     0      14393  0
```

I wrote a test C++ program in Visual Studio using the same Environment variables logic ...

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 

int main(int argc, char **argv, char** envp) {
    printf("Current compiler version is ... %d\n", _MSC_VER);
    printf("Current compiler full version is ... %d\n", _MSC_FULL_VER);
    printf("Current OSVersion is ... %s\n\n", System::Environment::OSVersion->VersionString);

    char** env;
    for (env = envp; *env != 0; env++)
    {
        char* thisEnv = *env;
        printf("%s\n", thisEnv);
    }

    cin.ignore();
    cin.ignore();

    return 0;
}
```

Results it (I won't print all environment variables except one)...

```
Current compiler version is ... 1900
Current compiler full version is ... 190024215
Current OSVersion is ... Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0

...
OS=Windows_NT
```

The above test program is configured with the Target Platform as `10.0.14393.0`.

Why does it think my OS is Windows 8?

Specs:

- Windows 10
- Version 10.0.14393 Build 14393
- Visual Studio 2015 (C++ project)

  - Target Platform 10.0.14393.0
- Powershell version 5.1

Comment: [`using namespace std;` is a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/2176813), never use it.

Comment: add [app.manifest to your project and add supportedOS GUIDs for 8.1 and 10](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40681525/1466046). now it works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get current version OS in Windows 10 in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40672109/get-current-version-os-in-windows-10-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design as the `GetVersionEx` and `VerifyVersionInfo` functions have a 'version lie' enabled by default on Windows 8.1 or later for all Win32 desktop applications.

You control the application of the 'version lie' by adding an embedded manifest to your EXE that includes the proper compatibility GUIDs:

```
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
   <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1"> 
       <application> 
           <!-- Windows Vista -->
           <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/> 
           <!-- Windows 7 -->
           <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
           <!-- Windows 8 -->
           <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"/>
           <!-- Windows 8.1 -->
           <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}"/>
           <!-- Windows 10 -->
           <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}"/>
       </application> 
   </compatibility>
</assembly>
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/windows-version-check) and [Manifest Madness](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/09/10/manifest-madness/)

Comment: Did this, and it works, but I get a warning (that also appears to be a lie) -- `manifest authoring warning 81010002: Unrecognized Element "compatibility" in namespace "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1"` -- I claim it is a lie because the compatibility tag actually worked and was able to return the correct windows version. Any idea what this is about, or how I can get rid of it?

Comment: It will depend on what version of the manifest tool (``MT.EXE``) you are using. This warning doesn't happen if you are using one that's more recent. Check your tool paths in your project to figure out which one you are using.