# C++ RegGetValue function not returning correct Windows OS Version

Tags: c++, windows

I'm using the below code in a console application to get my Windows OS version:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
  DWORD dataSize = 0;
  char buffer[256];
  dataSize = sizeof(buffer);

  RegGetValueA(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion", 
   "ProductName", RRF_RT_REG_SZ, 0, &buffer, &dataSize);

  cout << buffer << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I have Windows 10 Pro installed, but the function is returning Windows 10 Enterprise. I have even manually navigated using regedit to the specified key and under "Product Name" I can see Windows 10 Pro. [Here is an image of my regedit.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmBIG.png)

I ran another function `RtlGetProductInfo(10, 0, 0, 0, f);` and it returned the value of 0x48 for f, which according to [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724358(v=vs.85).aspx) I have Windows 10 Enterprise Evaluation.

Now, at this point, I understand that something is messed up with my Windows installation, but why would my first code return another value than what is displayed for `"ProductName"` in my registry editor?

**Edit:** I should add that I've run the code on another Windows PC and it returns the correct version on that computer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MSVC OSVersion returning incorrect version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47226240/msvc-osversion-returning-incorrect-version)

Comment: Is this a 32 bit app on 64 bit Windows by any chance?

Comment: You are looking at the wrong registry key, navigate to HKLM/Software/Wow6432Node/etc.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Why are you using the Registry at all? There are several Win32 API functions that can return the OS version number directly. `GetVersionEx()` (which requires manifestation on Windows 8.1+), or `RtlGetVersion()`, `NetServerGetInfo()`, or `NetWkstaGetInfo()` (all of which do not require any manifestation).

Comment: @MrEricSir Yes, it is. When I changed my configuration to 64 bit, I got the correct version. Why is that?

Comment: @fmcgarry See what Hans Passant commented above -- your program is in WOW64 mode, so it's reading from a different registry key. As to _why_ the value there is different, I have no idea. Would be interesting to test on a clean Windows 10 Pro installation to see if this is a bug.

Comment: @HansPassant When I navigate to where you directed me in Regedit I see that it's showing Windows 10 Enterprise, so that is indeed where it's coming from. As to _why_ it's like that I have no idea either. I must have done it on installation somehow, because I checked another Windows Pro PC and in both registry locations it reports the correct version. Thanks everyone!