# How to check windows version in C# on .NET 5.0 console app

Tags: c#, .net, console

Like im working on a "console game engine"
but it only works on Windows 10 since "custom colors" arent properly displayed on other versions, for example win8, instead they are just a bunch of unicode codes? "

[image: example.png]"

so i wanna check if windows version is 10.
and i did this

```
var workingSysVer = Environment.OSVersion.Version.ToString().Substring(0, 2);
            if (workingSysVer != "10")
            {
                Console.Title = "OS Version Warning";
                // other code
            }
```

Is there a better way to check version of windows?

Comment: Only Windows or multi-platform ?

Comment: The app is windows only, i mean it produces .exe file soo

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Windows Version - as in "Windows 10, version 1607"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39778525/how-to-get-windows-version-as-in-windows-10-version-1607) and [Detect Windows version in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819934/detect-windows-version-in-net)

Comment: I mean, i did something like this:

if(Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", "productName", "").ToString().Substring(0, 10) != "Windows 10")
{
// other stuff
}

Comment: @.KSZLAGK You can simplify by using `.StartWith("Windows 10")` to avoid potential `SubString` errors.

Comment: Oh, oh yea that will do

Comment: `.StartWith("Windows 10")`... and this is why Microsoft will have to skip Windows 100 ;)

Comment: @omajid Indeed, so the same as substring... `.StartWith("Windows 10 ") || == "Windows 10"` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use what you need from this (in addition to `OSVersion` you can use `osName` and `osRelease`) :

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Versioning;
using Microsoft.Win32;

string NL = Environment.NewLine;
string HKLMWinNTCurrent = @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion";

string osName = get(() => Registry.GetValue(HKLMWinNTCurrent, "productName", "").ToString());

string osRelease = get(() => Registry.GetValue(HKLMWinNTCurrent, "ReleaseId", "").ToString());
if ( !osRelease.IsNullOrEmpty() ) osRelease = $" ({ osRelease})";

string osVersion = Environment.OSVersion.Version.ToString();

string osType = Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem ? "64-bits" : "32-bits";

string clr = Environment.Version.ToString();

string dotnet = get(() =>
{
  var attributes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CustomAttributes;
  var result = attributes.FirstOrDefault(a => a.AttributeType == typeof(TargetFrameworkAttribute));
  return result == null
          ? ".NET Framework (unknown)"
          : result.NamedArguments[0].TypedValue.Value.ToString();
});

string Platform = $"{osName} {osType} {osVersion}{osRelease}{NL}{dotnet}{NL}CLR {clr}";

string get(Func<string> func)
{
  try { return func(); }
  catch { return "(undefined)"; }
}
```

*Example*

```html
Windows 10 Pro 64-bits 6.2.9200.0 (2009)
.NET Framework 4.7.2
CLR 4.0.30319.42000
```

**I never noticed that 6.2.9200 is [incorrect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_Windows_versions)... !?**

*Solution from @nap*: [How to get Windows Version - as in "Windows 10, version 1607"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39778525/how-to-get-windows-version-as-in-windows-10-version-1607/39778770#50693051)

*Explanation from @DanielDiPaolo*: [Detect Windows version in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819934/detect-windows-version-in-net)

Comment: Thanks! It is surely better to check that way

Comment: Will this also work in older windows 10 builds or server 2016/2019? Can I rely on this?

Comment: In Windows 11 the osName is still equal to "Windows 10 Pro" see here: https://imgur.com/a/SupZVV8