# How to add an application into context menu for any user using c# code

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, windows-10, contextmenu

How to add an application into context menu for any user using c# code. I used this solution.

```
RegistryKey _key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey($"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\Directory\\Background\\shell", true);
RegistryKey newkey = _key.CreateSubKey("Use Virtual Printer");

RegistryKey subNewkey = newkey.CreateSubKey("Command");
subNewkey.SetValue("", "C:\\yourApplication.exe");
subNewkey.Close();

newkey.Close();
_key.Close();
```

But I got Null Reference Exception in second line.

Comment: Are you running your program with administrator rights? These are required to get writeable access to this registry path.

Comment: no. How can i change this in a way so any user can get this

Comment: i should use **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\directory\shell** for any user. right?

Comment: That's current user only. Have to take in account that operation may fail due permissions. also, look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728491/opensubkey-returns-null-for-a-registry-key-that-i-can-see-in-regedit-exe

Comment: Sorry it does not help