# How to clear a FileDialog's dropdown history?

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, history, openfiledialog, savefiledialog

It seems that my application is remembering previously saved/opened files. How can clear the recent history and prevent the application from keeping track of saved/opened files in the future?

I want to be able to do this from the application, without requiring client involvement.

*I suppose that the information is saved to the registry.*

Comment: In my perspective, I would not recommend an application which can clear the OS history or plays with registry. It might cause a security violation in the user environment or network. As file dialog is the windows provided it remembers the last access path and all. I would suggest you to provided your own dialog if you don't want expose the recent items to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Where is recently opened files](http://blog.iordanov.info/?p=89)

And then delete them: [How to delete a registry value in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531151/how-to-delete-registry-value-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

just: openfiledialog.FileName = "";