# OpenFileDialog not displaying any history in dropdown

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

I've searched a lot of threads here at SO, but anything I found was just where the history should be stored and how it could be deleted, like here:

[How to clear a FileDialog's dropdown history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296229/how-to-clear-a-filedialogs-dropdown-history)

I've looked at the described registry path, but the path where the recent opened files should be stored explained here

[View the list of recently opened files in Windows width C#](http://blog.iordanov.info/?p=89)

is missing the last folder OpenSaveMRU on my machine.

**Maybe there is the problem already located? How could i solve it?**

My OS is Windows 7 x64 with latest available patches.

**EDIT 17.12.2013 10:40:**

I found out that the OpenSaveMRU key got renamed under Vista/Windows 7 to OpenSavePidlMRU .
[OpenSaveMRU and LastVisitedMRU](http://computer-forensics.sans.org/blog/2010/04/02/openrunsavemru-lastvisitedmru)

---

I'm showing the dialog like that:

```
System.Win32.OpenFileDialog dialog = new System.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
dialog.AddExtension = true;
dialog.CheckPathExists = true;
dialog.DefaultExt = ".xaml";
dialog.Filter = "Xaml files (.xaml)|*xaml|All files|*.*";
dialog.FilterIndex = 0;

Boolean? result = dialog.ShowDialog();
if (result.HasValue && result.Value)
{
   // business logic
}
```

After opening some files the drop down history still keeps being empty.
Any thoughts how to solve this?

**The solution is**:

The defined filter for xaml has been wrong. There is missing a dot between * and xaml.

Comment: Try to declare the OpenFileDialog out of method. Reasonably recent list Is in object level, and you create it every time.

Comment: @lomed well, i tried already declaring dialog object as private member outside my calling method, but it still had the same results. The history doesn't gets displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it!
The problem is this line

```
Filter = "Xaml files (.xaml)|*xaml|All files|*.*",
```

Because **xaml* is not Extension.
Instead Write

```
Filter = "Xaml files (.xaml)|*.xaml|All files|*.*",
```

Comment: For your time and effort you get the Answer although i found out :)

Comment: oof, Now I see that this is exactly what you wrote last comment :(

Answer (score 1):

try use the same dialog object each time:

```
System.Win32.OpenFileDialog dialog = new System.Win32.OpenFileDialog()
{
    AddExtension = true,
    CheckPathExists = true,
    DefaultExt = ".xaml",
    Filter = "Xaml files (.xaml)|*xaml|All files|*.*",
    FilterIndex = 0
};

private void FileOpen()
{
    Boolean? result = dialog.ShowDialog();
    if (result.HasValue && result.Value)
    {
        // business logic
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that didn't change the behaviour. I tested it by starting from vs2010 and also starting the executable. I was also wondering how other applications do it because if i look at them, they display the history also after i close and reopen the application.

Comment: i use System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog(), and it show everything, even the first time.
You have reason not to use it?

Comment: No i don't think there could be a reason it was just implemented with that other namespace. I tried it, but it also has no effect :(. I also tried with a completely new WindowsFormsApplication and copy pasted the calling method but its also not displaying the history.

Comment: And in other software, Word for example, history appears? Maybe it is set at the level of the operating system.

Comment: Yes, Visual Studio, Notepad++ every application which provides an OpenFileDialog is displaying the history.

Comment: i have found the solution. The defined filter for *.xaml Files has been wrong. There is missing a dot between * and the string xaml. O MY GOD :) Thanks for your help and time

Comment: When you choose "All Files" in drop down filter, it shows the recent files?

Comment: yes and after correcting the filter information it works for xaml also.