# unable to delete registry Folder in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to delete the registry Folder using C# code but it throws an exception I.e. key doesn't exists...!!!
but if key not exists the how then registry object should be not null
But in this case it dnt show it as null it contained some value
this my code

```
bool IsDeleted = false;
            try
            {
                regkey = regkey.Replace(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\", "");
                using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(regkey, true))
                {
                    if (key != null)//here it show that key is exists
                    {
                        IsDeleted = DeleteKey(key, regkey);//in this line It generate exception

                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }
             return IsDeleted;
```

this is Delete Code

```
 public static bool DeleteKey(RegistryKey hKey, string strPath)
        {
            bool flag1 = false;
            int num1 = 0;
            int num2 = 0;
            try
            {
                num2 = 1;
                hKey.DeleteSubKeyTree(strPath);
                flag1 = true;
            }
            catch (Exception obj1) //when (?)
            {
                Exception exception2 = (Exception)obj1;
                Exception exception1 = exception2;
                if (num1 == 0)
                {
                    num1 = -1;
                    switch (num2)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            {
                                goto Label_0058;
                            }
                    }
                    throw;
                }
            }
        Label_0058:
            if (num1 != 0)
            {
            }
            return flag1;
        }
```

please help me for this
thnx

Comment: seems like duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531151/how-to-delete-a-registry-value-in-c-sharp

Comment: above link value is deleted I want to delete Folder

Comment: then please mention properly in your question, so someone can guide you properly.

Comment: If `DeleteKey` is throwing a exception why did you not show the code for it?

Comment: here is my updated code

Comment: 1) Why the heck are you using goto's and 2) what is the [specific exception details](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saraford/archive/2008/08/07/did-you-know-you-can-copy-the-exception-details-with-one-click-from-the-exception-assistant-276.aspx) you are getting?

Comment: Cannot delete a subkey tree because the subkey does not exist.bt key present in the registry

Comment: WOW64 registry redirection?

Comment: Example value of regkey?

Comment: I got my and its due to permissions to access the registry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this occur due to the permissions issue in windows 7

```
try
            {
                new System.Security.Permissions.RegistryPermission(System.Security.Permissions.PermissionState.Unrestricted).Assert();
                hKey.DeleteSubKeyTree(strPath);
                flag1 = true;
            }
            catch (Exception obj1) //when (?)
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                System.Security.Permissions.RegistryPermission.RevertAssert();
            }
```

You can embed this manifest into your application.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<asmv1:assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication" />
    <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
        <security>
            <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
                <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
            </requestedPrivileges>
        </security>
    </trustInfo>
</asmv1:assembly>
```

Comment: still it gives error like Object reference not set to an instance of an object.