# C# Delete Registry Value

Tags: c#, registry

I want to delete registry value by clicking on button.

I have code, but when i click on the button, it says "No value exists with that name".

But there's a value.

Here's the code:

```
        string cryptographyKey = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography";
        RegistryKey ckey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(cryptographyKey, true);
        ckey.DeleteValue("MachineGuid");
```

When i debugging it, the error is on `ckey.DeleteValue("MachineGuid");`
There's a value called `MachineGuid` exists in the location `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography`

But why do i get that error?

Comment: Did you manage SysWOW6432Node redirection?

Comment: take a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531151/how-to-delete-a-registry-value-in-c-sharp

Comment: @OAH I tried the method from the link, and i still get the same error.